# Memory Limit Exceeded : When using Java Scanner

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

**Problem :**

`standard input/output: 2s/128000 kB`

You are given a chessboard of size N x N, where the top left square is black. Each square contains a value. Find the sum of values of all black square and all white squares.

`1 <= N <= 1000`

**Solution 1:**
Now when I am using `Scanner` to take the input, it is throwing `memory limit exceeded` for one test case

```java
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
long n = sc.nextLong();

long wsum = 0;
long bsum = 0;

for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    for(int j=0; j<n; j++) {
        if((i+j)%2 != 0 ) {
            wsum = wsum + sc.nextLong();
        } 
        else {
            bsum = bsum + sc.nextLong();
        }
    }
}
```

**Solution 2:** When I am using the `BufferedReader` all test cases are passing

```java
BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        
int N = Integer.parseInt(read.readLine());
        
int mat[][] = new int[N][N];
for(int i = 0; i < N; i++){
      String str[] = read.readLine().trim().split(" ");
      for(int j = 0; j < N; j++)
          mat[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(str[j]);            
}

long sum =0, sum1 = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < N; j++)
    {
         if((i+j)%2 == 0)
             sum += mat[i][j];
         else sum1 += mat[i][j];
    }
            
}
```

Now I know `BufferedReader` is efficient while reading file but that should throw `time limit exceeded`.

I would like to understand how `BufferedReader` is making this program more memory efficient as compared to `Scanner` class.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @marstran I will improve readability

Comment: Please show us the stacktrace for the first solution.  The stacktrace for the `OutOfMemoryError`.

Comment: @StephenC submitted to an online judge which throws the error `MLE : Memory limit exceeded`

Comment: @AtulKumar We don't really care about your online judge; please provide the stack-trace. And frankly speaking, I cannot see any tests there. Likely the condition `(i+j) % 2 != 0` is at fault... and the 2nd version doesn't use `str.length()` as a condition, as it is probably supposed to.

Comment: @IuriiDrozdov I am using `long` in both the solution

Comment: @IuriiDrozdov I am saying **solution2**  is working with `long`

Comment: ah, sorry didn't understand the question

Comment: The first step to debugging is to make a [mre] so that you can run this in your own debugger.